# Add a column to SQL query that signifies the number of rows in the query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have some query which is basically this

```
 select *  
 from tiket 
 where storno = 'yes' 
   and time_storno > '2016-07-25 11:48:48.062' 
 order by time_storno asc limit 100
```

Can I modify this query to add one more column that has in each row the number of rows from this table? This table may have less rows than 100.

Comment: Basically you want to store the count of rows in the table in each of the records in the table ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [a window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
select *, count(*) over () as row_count
from tiket 
where storno = 'yes' 
  and time_storno > '2016-07-25 11:48:48.062' 
order by time_storno asc
```

This will contain the number of rows that satisfy the criteria (so `row_count` matches the number of rows returned by that query).

If you want to get the **total** number of rows (without the `where` clause) use a scalar sub-query

```
select *, (select count(*) from tiket) as row_count
from tiket 
where storno = 'yes' 
  and time_storno > '2016-07-25 11:48:48.062' 
order by time_storno asc
```

Comment: Does using `over` negate the need to group?

Comment: @JohnHC: yes, read the link to the tutorial on window functions from my answer

Comment: sorry , I forgot to add something in my query I would be grateful if you could take a look at it once more, with this slight modification (with limit ).

Comment: @RogerFederer: the second statement will also work with a `limit` clause (but won't make the statement faster obviously)